# create-react-app production build renames functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am working on building a react app which I will link to (https://github.com/Team6479/TeamTracker) in the event that additional context is needed for this issue. I have created a class ([ActionIndex](https://github.com/Team6479/TeamTracker/blob/master/src/helpers/ConfigParser/ActionIndex.ts)) that imports and indexes an initial set of functions in a separate file ([actions.ts](https://github.com/Team6479/TeamTracker/blob/master/src/helpers/ConfigParser/actions.ts)) so they can be referenced by their string name. When running a local development copy (with react-scripts start) it works fine and the indexer works as expected, however when deploying to production the function name seems to have been changed (In my case the expected name was "mean" and the actual was "E").

Given that this is occurring on the production build only I am guessing it has something to do with webpack, however due to using create-react-app I am not sure how to fix this as I have little influence over what webpack does.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is configured to optimise your bundle for the production environment. It minifies your code, it should be in your production build. If you want to avoid that you will have to alter the production webpack config.

Read about Minification here: [Webpack production](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/)

Answer (score 0):

This process is called Minification.
Minification refers to the process of removing unnecessary or redundant data without affecting how the resource is processed by the browser - e.g. code comments and formatting, removing unused code, using shorter variable and function names, and so on.
Webpack is configured to do this automatically as it a a good practice and helps in faster rendering of pages (short names => short file size).
You don't need to fix it as nothing is wrong, but if still you choose to do, be sure you are rock solid on what your use case is and what you want to achieve.